# Page ressources appear crypted when HTTPS / SSL on

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, static, display

I have been using a SSL layer along with a Wab Application Firewall (SUCURI) for some time now).

Since a few days, I see something I never seen my entire life. I suspect a HTTPS encryption problem since that only happens when browsing with HTTPS.

Some of my pages ressources (css, jr, and sometimes cached html) are displayed crypted. I am under the impression that hapens mostly on safari (Os X and iOs).

Did someone experienced the same ?

[SCREENSHOT CSS ressources get crypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2O10.jpg)

[SCREENSHOT JS ressources get crypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs8K5.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your web server and your WAF?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to logs on SUCURI WAF. But I changed my CDN/WAF to cloudflare and the problem is gone... It's much slower (sucuri was sooo fast), but problem is gone.